# Python re.match not strict enough

Tags: python, regex

I have problem understanding regexp matching. In short this small script gives wrong result.

In:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

base = '/show/summer/2015/party/my_brand/'

pt1 = '^/show/(?P<season>.+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>.+)/(?P<brand>.+)/$'
pt2 = '^/show/(?P<season>.+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>.+)/$'


print base, '==', pt1, re.match(pt1, base) is not None
print base, '==', pt2, re.match(pt2, base) is not None
```

Out:

```
/show/summer/2015/party/my_brand/ == ^/show/(?P<season>.+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>.+)/(?P<brand>.+)/$ True
/show/summer/2015/party/my_brand/ == ^/show/(?P<season>.+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>.+)/$ True
```

Clearly I was expecting only pt1 to be matched. I am pretty sure my pattern is wrong and I should change something to be more greedy (guesswork in here).

Anyone call point me what I do not know about regexp.

Comment: `>>> False is not None`. Try running that

Comment: Looks like `"(?P<type>.+)"` is matching `"party/my_brand"` because `.` matches any character (including a slash).

Comment: @khelwood: Yep, replacing `.` (any character) with `[^/]` (any character that isn't a slash) would do it.

Comment: Great, that is what I am looking for, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"(?P<type>.+)"` will match `"party/my_brand"` because `.` matches any character (including the slash).

To prevent it matching a slash, you could use:

```
pt2 = '^/show/(?P<season>[^/]+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<type>[^/]+)/$'
```

where `[^/]` means "any character that is not a slash".

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [^/]+ instead of a .+ to capture the text, otherwise the dot can also capture the slash.